# Render .csv file on browser instead of downloading

Tags: java, spring-boot, media-type

In my `Spring-boot` application, to render the files of types `.txt`, `.pdf` I am setting the `HttpHeader` with the following properties.

```
private HttpHeaders getAppropriateHeaders( String fileType, String fileName )
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    switch ( fileType )
    {
        case FileConstants.PDF_TYPE :
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            break;

        case FileConstants.TXT_TYPE :
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            break;

        case FileConstants.PNG_TYPE :
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
            break;

        case FileConstants.JPEG_TYPE :
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            break;

        default :
            // If set file will be downloaded
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);
            break;
    }

    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    return headers;

}
```

So far the `pdf`, `txt`, `png`, `jpeg` files are being rendered on the browser. But What I need to do render `.csv` files in the same way? What `contentType` should be set in the `HttpResponse`?

Comment: That's up to the *browser*, not your API.

Comment: But the browser is throwing error `localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION`

Comment: Your comment seems unrelated to your question. the question as it is now asks how to render csv in web browser, not why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header you are setting tells the browser that you would like to show contents of the file inline in the browser:

```
headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName);
```

The browser will do it, if that's supported. For example, showing PDF files inline in the browser is supported by most, if not all, modern browsers; with CSV, it's quite the opposite.

However, the error your are getting (described in the comment: `localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION`), is correct for CSV files, because **you are setting Content-Disposition header twice** for CSV: first time in the `default` case for `switch` statement, second time after the `switch` statement).

Correct it by handling `text/csv` in your `switch` statement.

Comment: Got it...So is there any way to render `.csv` and `.doc` file on browser (Modern browsers)?